# Can a user with just READER access on resource group still use the resources (not manage but actually use it)

Tags: azure, rbac

Can a user with just READER access on resource group still use the resource (NOT manage with activities like modify or scale it but actually use it like RDP in case of VM and add tables etc in case of DB).

Scenario:
If i have an Azure SQL Database (AZSQL) in a Resource group (RG), where user (USR) has just READER access on the resource group and its contents.
Will the user (USR) be able to work with the database to store\retrieve data and do all CRUD (CREATE, READ, UPDATE and DELETE) operations on it.

The aim is to restrict the user access to just using resources and not give them the ability to modify the configuration or setup of resources.
Example scenario is mentioned above.

PS: Updated scenario to SQL DB when i realized that CosmosDB is still pending on RBAC with Azure AD

Comment: What do you mean with *using*? Access the data in an application or access to the resource in the azure portal?

Comment: @PeterBons: i have clarified more in my example now, do take a look.

Comment: @TonyJu: i do not want to use contribute, its kind of uncomfortable to use it for normal usage of resource. That will give them a capability to manage the resource too. This is something i am trying to separate, use of resource and management or scaling of resource

Comment: @mohitsharma That's why I recommended you to use custom role. You can define the role by yourself to meet your needs.

Comment: @mohitsharma  Do click on "Mark as Answer" on the post that helps you and vote it as helpful, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular scenario, it is certainly possible to do so. I haven't tried it myself but it is possible to assign Role Based Access Control (RBAC) roles to a Cosmos DB account.

What you would need to do is assign the user [`Cosmos DB Account Reader Role`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#cosmos-db-account-reader-role).

To add a user and assign role, please see this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#add-users-and-assign-roles).

User will then be able to read data from an account. I'm not sure what other operations a user will be able to perform in that role.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this on my side. If you assign the user [Cosmos DB Account Reader Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#cosmos-db-account-reader-role), the user will be able to read data from it, but can not do other operations(like store and delete).

You need to assign the user contributor role, then the user will be able to store data and also configure the settings. So the built-in roles will not be applicable for you.

You can create your own [custom roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) to meet your needs. Just like built-in roles, you can assign custom roles to users, groups, and service principals at subscription, resource group, and resource scopes.